# C# How to Debug inside the DT.Rows.Add method

Tags: c#, datatable, visual-studio-debugging

I have the following method (below), which throws this error: "***Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow***".
The table contains 192526 rows and 9 columns.

Is there a way to place a breakpoint for each item inside the "**dt.Rows.Add()**"? I.e. can I define which Row and which Column this is failing on, etc?

I could do a "StepInto" once I reach this line. And I saw this error "*error CS0103: The name 'dt' does not exist in the current context*" (I assume that is not the one that is causing the eventual failure), in the line "*dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field("Balance")),*"  But - there are way too many entries to do "StepOver" for each, and before it gets into next one.

```
  public DataTable AddTrailer(DataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt.TableName.Equals("Summary"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summary Table");

                dt.Rows.Add(
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("Balance")),
                    dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("Total1")),
                    dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("Total2"))
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown in the AddTrailer - Summary");
            throw;
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

If I use the suggestion as "*dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => (long)dr.Field("Balance"))*" - I will get another error: "*{"Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.Couldn't store <21488943305> in Balance|Current Balance Column. Expected type is Int32."}*"

I cannot even figure out why it is complaining as the number of rows (or rows * columns) should not be that high (to be outside of the regular int).

Comment: Try `dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => (long)dr.Field<int>("Balance")),` also `throw ex;` is a bad idea as it will wipe the stack trace, use `throw;` instead

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks. When I use your suggestion now I'm getting a new one: "{"Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.Couldn't store <21488943305> in Balance|Current Balance Column.  Expected type is Int32."}"

Comment: Guess you need to change the `DataTable` definition to use `long`. You can't fit such a big number in `int` there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems that the SUM was indeed over the Max for the Int32. To get around the problem - I copied those columns into new ones but of the Int64 type instead (and then removed the original Int32 columns). And then it was working fine.

```
    private Int64 CopyColumnAndGetSum(DataTable dt, string currentColumnName, string newColumnName)
    {
        Int64 sum = 0;
        DataColumn colBal64 = new DataColumn();
        colBal64.ColumnName = newColumnName;
        colBal64.DataType = typeof(Int64);
        dt.Columns.Add(colBal64);

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            dr[newColumnName] = dr[currentColumnName];
        }
        sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr?.Field<Int64?>(newColumnName) ?? 0);
        return sum;
    }
```